# Socket.io rooms issue

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I'm using `Socket.io` to make my application communicate with my server, the problem is when I'm trying to show connected clients data the server crashes and returns this error:

```
/app/index.js:184
var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.idStanza].sockets;
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:184:65)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at /app/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

It returns this error even if 3 or more clients are still connected to the room. 
The code I'm using to show clients data is the following:

```
socket.on("getClassifica", function () {
        var players = [];

        var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.idStanza].sockets;

        for (var clientId in clients) {
            var socketOfClient = io.sockets.connected[clientId];

            console.log("Client name = " + socketOfClient.nomeGiocatore);
            console.log("puntiOttenuti = " + socketOfClient.puntiOttenuti);

            var player = { name: socketOfClient.nomeGiocatore, puntiOttenuti: socketOfClient.puntiOttenuti };
            players.push(player);
        }

        io.to(socket.idStanza).emit("sendClassifica", { players: players });
});
```

Comment: As far as i undertstand it really shouldn't give you this, but at the time you are trying to get the sockets out of `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.idStanza]`, if it can't find a valid object then you are gonna try to get `undefined.sockets` which gives you this TypeError. Maybe you can check first `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.idStanza]` this is a valid object and then try to get sockets out of it?